# SQLCMD Usage in Batch file

Tags: sql-server-2005, batch-file, sqlcmd

Hi All I am Writing a Batch Script Which has to read a set of SQL Files which exists in a Folder then Execute Them Using SQLCMD utiliy.

When I am Trying to execute it does not create any output file. I am not sure where I am wrong and I am not sure how to debug the script. Can someone help me out with script?

```
@echo off

FOR %F IN (C:\SQLCMD*.SQL) DO sqlcmd -S LENOVO-C00 -U yam -P yam!@ -i %F -o C:\SEL.txt -p -b

IF NOT [%ERRORLEVEL%] ==[0] goto get_Error

:Success echo Finished Succesffuly exit /B 0 goto end

:get_error echo step Failed exit /B 40

:end
```

Comment: `if not [%errorlevel%] ==[0]` should be `if errorlevel 1`. Avoid using the pseudo-variable unless you have to since it can break.

Comment: It should be noted that it isn't necessary to keep your sql scripts in separate files. You can put the entire SQL statements inside the batch file and make them very human readable by using line separators with the carrot character and delayed expansion enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actually in a batch file (not being executed by hand at the command line), then the `%F` variables need to have the `%` characters doubled-up because of the way that cmd.exe executes the lines read from the batch file:

```
FOR %%F IN (C:\SQLCMD*.SQL) DO sqlcmd -S LENOVO-C00 -U yam -P yam!@ -i %%F -o C:\SEL.txt -p -b
```

Though I would have thought you'd get a

```
F was unexpected at this time.
```

error if you only had one `%` character in front of the variable name.

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for the Reply.After Adding the %%  I was able to Run the batch file. But the script was not able to loop or iterate the file's.

Comment: Anoop - comment out the "@echo off" so you can see exactly what commands the `for` command is trying to execute. That may give you a clue to what's going wrong.  Alternatively, change the "DO sqlcmd ..." to "DO echo sqlcmd ..." to maybe help debug what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try to right click the Batch File and run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer would be more like this:

```
FOR %%F "usebackq" IN (`dir.exe C:\SQLCMD*.SQL`) DO ...
```